# Remove iframe with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, iframe

I am trying to remove iFrame tags in my documents.
This is the function. But it don't seem to work. Here is my sample code

```
<script>
function removeiframe() {
            alert("Hello Lovely World");
            var markup = document.body.innerHTML;
            
            var filtered=markup.replace(/(<iframe.*?>.*?<\/iframe>)/g,"");
            alert("he: " + markup);
//markup = Regex.Replace(markup, @"<script.*?/script>", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
//markup = Regex.Replace(markup, @"<iframe.*?/iframe>", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
markup = filtered;
document.body.innerHTML = markup + "<hr><hr>HELLO";
        }
</script>
<body onload="removeiframe()">
    
        <iframe marginheight="0" src="http://www.hotelanswer.com" marginwidth="0" frameborder="0" height="180" scrolling="no" width="210"></iframe><br>
</body>
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here's a script you can run that will remove all the iframes from your document. Here's an example of this working: http://jsfiddle.net/5hh9H/

```
var iframes = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
    iframes[i].parentNode.removeChild(iframes[i]);
}
```

Comment: this code doesn't work properly if there is more than one iframe, since iframes in this case is a live collection, which updates as long as we remove iframes from the document

Comment: @s.ermakovich I don't think that's necessarily correct, but I changed it to a static collection anyways.

Answer (score 8):

Pure Javascript code:

```
document.querySelectorAll('iframe').forEach(
  function(elem){
    elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You didn't mention why you need to remove iframes in the document.

I do it in order to prevent Clickjacking attack. But it will work in any cases.

You need this:

```
<style id="defendClickjack" type="text/css">body{display:none;}</style>
```

and then

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (self === top) {
        var defendClickjack = document.getElementById("defendClickjack");
        antiClickjack.parentNode.removeChild(defendClickjack);
    }
    else {
        top.location = self.location;
    }
</script>
```

You can find more information here:

- https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking

Answer (score 4):

Slight improvement here to [Matt's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15103641/15626554) original example if you want to only do it on mobile. For me, the use case was that I'm using a Vimeo embed on my site to create a video background. I needed to ditch the video on mobile for performance. This does the job.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {      
    let isMobile = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width:650px)").matches;
        if (isMobile) {
            var iframes = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
            for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
            iframes[i].parentNode.removeChild(iframes[i]);
            }
        }
    });
```

s.ermakovich's comment about code not working properly with more than one iframe is not 'wrong' but a bit misleading...and depends on the situation. My Vimeo iFrame had a child frame making requests that continued after DOM complete. Matt's code **did** destroy both.

In my case my ***2nd iframe*** was a ***direct child*** of the ***parent***. The code might not work if you have several iframes on a page that are not direct children of the same parent and you just copy and paste that code. In this case you need to be more specific:

If you have multiple iFrames on your page you can add specificity to your query selector. Your choice if you want to use querySelectorAll() or not based on the situation, but I see no reason why querySelector() can't be used either.

```
document.querySelector(".foo > bar iframe")
document.querySelector("foo bar > iframe")
```

If you have a grid of iframes, perhaps several embedded videos in a row perhaps

```
document.querySelectorAll("foo > .bar > iframe")
```

or maybe better from the same data source...

```
document.querySelectorAll("iframe[data-src]")
```

Someone please correct me if I'm wrong somewhere

Answer (score 0):

You should put the iframe inside of a div element.

```
<div id="kk">
  //your iframe
</div>
```

Then use jQuery to remove the iframe.

```
$('#kk').click(function(){
   $(this).html("");
});
```

This is a possible solution.