# JavaScript: Why targeting two iterations in a loop to remove all iframe elements in the DOM

Tags: javascript, iframe, ecmascript-6

I came across [this loop here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15103641/9303970) used to remove all `iframe` elements in the DOM with vanilla JS:

```
var iframes = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
    iframes[i].parentNode.removeChild(iframes[i]);
}
```

In the last line of the loop why did the author targeted the iteration of the collection hold by the `iframes` variable, **twice**?

In other words, why the syntax is `iframes[i].parentNode.removeChild(iframes[i]);` and not something simpler like the pseudocode `removeChild(iframes[i])`?

I wondered if this could be done in a shorter way without using the term `iframes[i]` twice, but once so there won't be an alleged "duplication".

Sorry if anything I wrote seems absurd.

Comment: `.removeChild` is a method of an Element, and is used for removing a child of the Element, so to remove `iframes[i]`, you need to call it from its `.parentNode`

Comment: You can, however, do `iframes[i].remove()` in more modern browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because if all you have is the child node, you need it twice.  You need:

```
parent.removeChild(child)
```

But, if you don't have parent, then you have to get the parent from the child with `child.parentNode` like this:

```
child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
```

Where `iframes[i]` in your code is `child`.

---

Note, a more verbose version of your code would probably be more obvious:

```
var iframes = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
var child, parent;
for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
    child = iframes[i];
    parent = child.parentNode;
    parent.removeChild(child);
}
```

---

Note: In a modern browser, you could just do:

```
 child.remove()
```

Which in your code would be:

```
 iframes[i].remove()
```

which was added precisely to prevent the redundant reference that `.removeChild()` often requires.

---

> I wondered if this could be done in a shorter way without using the term iframes[i] twice, but once so there won't be an alleged "duplication".

In a modern browser, one could do this:

```
var iframes = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
    iframes[i].remove();
}
```

Comment: In the more verbose version of the code, why did you use the terminology of `parent` and `child`? Only aesthetically to accord to the `removeChild()` method? I ask this because I'm not sure that `iframe` must be a child of anything (besides the `body`)...

Comment: @user9303970 - Any element in the DOM is a child of something and has a parent.  An iframe tag is a regular element in the DOM.  It has position in the DOM and a parent.  It happens to be a container element for another document, but it is inserted into the page just like any other DOM element.  It's parent can be the current body or it can be some other containing element such as a `div` element.  You can literally insert an iframe into any other container element and that would be its parent.

Comment: I think I understand the source of my confusion: To target DOM elements I usually use selectors, but in the case of `iframe` AFAIK, usually there aren't any selectors.

Comment: @user9303970 - The iframe itself is just a DOM element that you can target with any selector you want.  For example, in your code `document.querySelectorAll('iframe');` is targeting the iframe tag itself.  If that tag had a class or id on it, you could target those with a similar query.  You cannot target content within that iframe directly from the parent document.  You'd have to fetch the document from the iframe and do a selector query inside the iframe document itself.