# I am trying to re authenticate if there is any error

Tags: angular, azure, angular8, azure-ad-msal

I am getting error while trying to 'acquiresilenttoken' in 'MSAL' but i am not able to execute 'handleRedirectCallback'. I tried adding a debugger but it never goes inside 'handleRedirectCallback' what could be the reason. Below is the code i am using.

```
if (err ) {
                                    //this.authService.logout();
                                    debugger

                                    this.authService.handleRedirectCallback((err:AuthError) => {
                                        debugger
                                        if (err) {

                                          console.error('Redirect Error: ', err.errorMessage);
                                          return;
                                        }
                                        debugger
                                        this.authService.loginRedirect();
                                        console.log('Redirect Success: ');
                                      });
                                    this.broadcastService.broadcast('msal:notAuthorized', err.message);
                                }
```

My MSALconfig :

```
"auth": {
        "clientId": "xxx",
        "authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx",
              "validateAuthority":"true",

              "postLogoutRedirectUri": "http://localhost:44399/",
              "navigateToLoginRequestUrl": true
    },
    "system":{
        "loadFrameTimeout":10000
    },
    "cache": {
      "cacheLocation": "localStorage"

    }
```

Comment: please include whats inside of your `handleRedirectCallback` method

Comment: @john Velasquez I have added above. This.authservixe.loginredirect(); but it doesn't enter this part. It just skips.

Comment: no i mean the code inside of your `handleRedirectCallback` not the call back function

Comment: @John Velasquez I have not added anything this comes from msal library right. I am just calling this to execute loginredirect.  Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: @JohnVelasquez Any idea on this? See what is happening is that the token renewal is failing for me. So i have added this code to renew the token.

Comment: in your `acquireTokenSilent` what is the error?

Comment: @JohnVelasquez I get token renewal operation failed due to timeout

Comment: can you post your msal config here

Comment: @JohnVelasquez I have added in the query that is above.

Comment: can you do inspect element, if you can see an iframe?

Comment: @JohnVelasquez I only see one i frame and that is below, but i dont see anything related to MSAL
<iframe><html><head></head><body></body></html></iframe>

Comment: can you try to remove it before calling the `acquireTokenSilent`

Comment: @JohnVelasquez How do i do that? I am not sure how it is getting created. But when token is not expired my application works fine. I face this issue only when token is expired

Comment: check it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103552/remove-iframe-with-javascript

Comment: @JohnVelasquez Are those iframes to do something with the timeout issue because this issue is only happening when token is expired

Comment: not sure but thats my guess base on the issue in github https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/1009, and looking at their code https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/1dbf0857769357a0494049ea2a6366d9c59acec6/lib/msal-core/src/UserAgentApplication.ts#L830

Comment: @JohnVelasquezThis is not working. I still face the same issue.

Comment: @JohnVelasquez Now after adding loadFrameTimeout i get the new token in local storage(cache) but when i aquiresilenttoken i get the expired token

Comment: Hi @ashish I think it would be better if your report this bug in their repo https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js, I honestly don't have any idea anymore how solve that issue, so sorry :(