# How to remove scripts after removing iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I loaded the iframe on my page. After some actions, the visitor can close the modal and the iframe will be removed from the page. but some javascript codes still running from the iframe source page.

Is there any way to clear the memory from the iframe js codes?

Comment: how did you **remove** `iframe`? If you have just hidden it, then it will still be functioning, but if remove the element completely, then it shouldn't.

Comment: Have you try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103552/remove-iframe-with-javascript